# How to not make ImageView so blurry when zooming - Titanium Studio

Tags: android, titanium

I'm designing an app made so that you can choose a map you want to view and the app will return the map image (.jpg file). I can get the map to display fine, but when I set zoom controls for it and zoom in to see the lettering on the image, the image gets distorted and blurry and I can't see any of the what the words say. Is there a way to prevent this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

`android:drawingCacheQuality="high"`

If you're using ImageView, though